# Packaged apps and mailto link and default email client

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Just wondering if it is possible to get a mailto link opened from inside a Chrome Packaged Apps without having the browser to show up when the default email client is not gmail.

For the moment, I do a window.open(myMailtoLink) that shows up Chrome with a new tab opened and launches Thunderbird too.

I would like to only get Thunderbird started or a webview for Gmail Client.

My purpose is to get the same behaviour from inside a packaged apps as from a java one using the `java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse("mailto:....")`.

Comment: did you try setting `window.location`?

Comment: It seems to do the trick. Thanks a lot CD !

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `window.location` instead of `window.open`.